# How to upload any Excel file into database?

Tags: excel, database, import

I have question about Excel file uploading into database (MySQL or another one). So, is there any options by which I can upload any/random Excel file? I'm not sure how to make it without structure in database but I want to make it automatically with HTML upload. I did it with PHP, HTML and AJAX but I have structure in database and that's an issue because I can't upload Excel file with different data structure. How to automate it?

Comment: This question is lacking information. Can you please elaborate on if you are updating an existing table, building a new table, etc?

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin, I know that you can import a CSV file, which is a format you can save Excel documents in.

Comment: So, if you have an Excel file (whether you already have it or want to make a new one) and you want it to upload with dinamically web-page in database. But database doesn't "depend" about Excel structure, I hope you understand me; any Excel file should be possible to upload.
No, CSV, I want to automate it so any user can work with, something like this page but with database:
https://codebeautify.org/excel-to-html